# Disable "The publisher could not be verified" while tarting .NET console app from share folder

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, process

I am trying to run a .NET console app from a shared network folder using method `Process.Start`.

Everytime the console app starts I get the message "The publisher could not be verified" and Windows asks for user confirmation. How can I disable this dialog? I do not want to buy a digital certificate.

Answer (score 7):

within your .net application when you use "Process.Start"

use the feature Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false.

so ...

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

what this does is it allows you to launch EXES (and only exes) directly without using the Explorer(shell). 
This will bypass any IE Security Zone checks. The Explorer by default includes the IEZone check and thus will
 give you a security warning if the application you are running is not 'trusted' (specifically in a trusted zone).

Now you cannot use 'false' if you want to launch a 'PDF' for example.  This only works for Exes.

Last bit of information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349795(WS.10).aspx

these bits of info, which a MS rep just provided me, may provide a way to trust the publisher of a signed application by using Software Restriction Policies.   I haven't looked into this yet, but for those that need to continue with this further... this looks like another way to address part (1) .